# How to target the right HTML sheet with Javascript for multilingual website?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a multilingual website (Fr / En). I work with a template so cannot modify the HTML but I have access so the CSS and Javascript. I need to redirect a link from my menu to an external site, which I did with this code:
[...]

```
<div class="container">
<nav>
<li class="itemsub">
<a class="itemLink" href="https://ksf.ca/cours-de-surf">
```

[...]

```
<script>
document.querySelector("body > header > div.headerPanel > div.mainMenuWrap > div > div > nav > ul > li:nth-child(7) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a").href = "https://ksf.ca/cours-de-surf";
</script>
```

It worked well but now I need to redirect the same selector but to the english page. How Can I target the HTML sheet I want to use, more specifically, the Html lang="en" ?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean `html[lang="en"]`?

Comment: If you're looking for the English version of that link, it's https://ksf.ca/river-surfing-lessons/?lang=en

Comment: Yes I mean html[lang="en"] . Basically, I want that when my site is in French and that someone clicks on my nav li "Activité", it redirects them to the french page Activité of another website. And when they are on the site in English and they click on the "Activities", it redirects them to the english page Activities of the other website.

Comment: if you are on http://ksf.shoplightspeed.com/us/ and click on Activities / River Surfing , it should redirect you to https://ksf.ca/river-surfing-lessons/?lang=en But right now it only redirect you to the french page https://ksf.ca/cours-de-surf/ because i wrote my JS script to redirect to the french page.

Comment: found it ! thanks anyways guys!!! <script>
var myUrl;
if(window.location.href.indexOf("us") > -1) {
 
 myUrl = 'https://ksf.ca/river-surfing-lessons/?lang=en';
 
} else {
 
 myUrl = 'https://ksf.ca/cours-de-surf';
}

document.querySelector("body > header > div.headerPanel > div.mainMenuWrap > div > div > nav > ul > li:nth-child(7) > ul > li:nth-child(1) > a").href = myUrl;

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript with json file like this https://github.com/dakk/jquery-multilang

Maybe help you

Answer (score 0):

you meaning something like this ?

make redirection

```
function changelang(){

   window.location = "englishpage.html";

}
```

in englishpage.hmtl you can use jquery. to locating you, to the wanted selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    top.location.href = '#selector';

});
```

or you can work with iframes.

```
<iframe id="frame" src="englishpage.html" height="200px">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<script>
function change(url) {
    var site = url;
    document.getElementById('frame').src = site;
}
</script>
```